# Certificate error while making a POST call for authenticating microsoft dynamics crm

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I downloaded the current microsoft dynamics crm SDK, and was trying to run the 'Main' class which is in the Walkthrough -> java2crmpack folder. I imported all the classes in eclipse and also generated stubs using wsdl.

So, while running this class I am facing certificate issues as the url is 'https'.

While making an authentication request it uses https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf url.

As this is a https call, it requires a certificate. In order to make it run, I downloaded the certificate and inserted it in the truststore. The truststore location is provided in eclipse configuration, still the error persists.

Error : "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

Kindly, help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error i have seen in two scenario's 
1. Code unable to locate Truststore properly
2. Truststore does not have valid chain